# ios, swift, core data + multiple tables

Tags: ios, core-data, swift

I'm very new to ios and swift. On a single view, how can I send two different fetch requests to two different table views? I have a class level fetchReq function that uses NSPredicate to take a parameter and give me the varied results that I want. The only place that knows which table is which is the tablView func, but it looks like the decision about which data to load gets made immediately on viewDidLoad. Could some kind soul help me restructure the core data code so that I get a different fetch request for each table?

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class CustomTableViewCell : UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet var l1: UILabel?
    @IBOutlet var l2: UILabel?

    func loadItem(#number: String, name: String) {
        l1!.text = number
        l2!.text = name
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet var tableView1: UITableView!
    //this is my second table - Ive connected it in the IB to this VC. both tables work, but are identical
    @IBOutlet var tableView2: UITableView!
    let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate).managedObjectContext
    var fetchedResultController: NSFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController()


    //the filtering happens inside this function. it gets called via didLoad, not cellsForRows
    func playerFetchRequest(playerType: String) -> NSFetchRequest {
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Players")
        let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "number", ascending: true)
        let filter = NSPredicate(format: "%K = %@", "type", playerType)
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
        fetchRequest.predicate = filter
        return fetchRequest
    }

    func getFetchedResultController() -> NSFetchedResultsController {
        fetchedResultController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: playerFetchRequest(playerType), managedObjectContext:managedObjectContext!, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
        return fetchedResultController
    }

    //remember: to create a table with multiple sections just implement the numberOfSectionsInTableView(_:) method
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if let numberOfRowsInSection = fetchedResultController.sections?[section].numberOfObjects
        {return numberOfRowsInSection} else {return 0}
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if (tableView == tableView2) {
        var playerType = "Forward"
        var cell:CustomTableViewCell = self.tableView1.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("customCell") as CustomTableViewCell
        let player = fetchedResultController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as DataModel
        cell.l2?.text = player.lastName + ", " + player.firstName
        cell.l1?.text = player.number
        println(tableView)
        return cell
        }
        else {
            var playerType = "Defender"
            var cell:CustomTableViewCell = self.tableView2.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("customCell") as CustomTableViewCell
            let player = fetchedResultController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as DataModel
            cell.l2?.text = player.lastName + ", " + player.firstName
            cell.l1?.text = player.number
            println(tableView)
            return cell
        }
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {
        tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
        println("You selected cell #\(indexPath.row)!")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        var nib = UINib(nibName: "CustomTableViewCell", bundle: nil)
        tableView1.registerNib(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "customCell")
        tableView2.registerNib(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "customCell")
        fetchedResultController = getFetchedResultController()
        fetchedResultController.delegate = self
        fetchedResultController.performFetch(nil)
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    func controllerDidChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController!) {
        tableView1.reloadData()
        tableView2.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: Both answers are correct - thanks very much for helping a newbie out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need 2 fetchedResultsControllers with the two different fetch requests for each table. If your tables delegates and datasources are both this view controller, you'll need to switch and provide the corresponding content... for example:

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if (tableView == tableView2)
    {
        return fetchedResultController2.sections?[section].numberOfObjects
    }
    else
    {
        return fetchedResultController.sections?[section].numberOfObjects
    }
}
```

Another option would be to create 2 custom MYTableViewDataSource objects and set the datasource for each table view to that... It might make it more obvious when you've got unexpected behaviour and make the data easier to control.

Answer (score 1):

Just establish two separate NSFetchedResultsController objects, one for each table:

```
var forwardFetchedResultController: NSFetchedResultsController
var defenderFetchedResultController: NSFetchedResultsController
```

then in `viewDidLoad` create them with different NSFetchRequests for each.  And in your tableView functions, use the correct fetched results controller for the correct table.